# .htaccess restrict media folder in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to figure out how to use this in a wordpress environment:

From: [Block direct url access but allow download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127153/php-how-can-i-block-direct-url-access-to-a-file-but-still-allow-it-to-be-downl)

1st:
.htaccess(in uploads folder)

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

2nd: (in wp-content folder "thePHPfile.php")

```
if( !empty( $_GET['name'] ) )
{

 //if( is_user_logged_in() )
  //{
    $file_name = preg_replace( '#[^-\w]#', '', $_GET['name'] );
    $the_file = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/oprotunity.jpg";
    //$the_file = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/{$file_name}.jpg";
    if( file_exists( $the_file ) )
    {
      header( 'Cache-Control: public' );
      header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
      header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$the_file}" );
      header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
      header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
      readfile( $the_file );

      exit;
    }
  //}
}
```

If I comment out the is_user_logged_in statement it works like a charm. I would like to add some conditional statements so I can serve the file to a role or even specific users by id or name. I can to the leg work but I am not sure how to get the needed functions from WordPress.

in the src area I put (wp-content directory)/thePHPfile.php?name=my-image-name

How do I use wordpress functions in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call Wordpress functions from an arbitrary script you'll need to include the Wordpress "start". This is **not** index.php. The file you need to include is `wp-blog-header.php` from your wordpress root directory. Once this is loaded, it will give you access to all the Wordpress functions.

Comment: <?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

Comment: In you opinion is this a good method to filter out users from seeing certain media files?

Comment: @Ernest: it is only as safe as the authentication measure itself. It's a good way to do it, though - in principle.

Comment: THANKS ALOT THAT WAS EASY AND WORKED LIKE A CHARM