# allow access to download file when request from my website

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website for downloading movies.
On this website just VIP users can download files and movies.
Users shouldn't be able to enter the URL into the browser and downloading the file.

I want to do something with `.htaccess` that when a download request from my website is received, the download would start automatically, otherwise the user is redirected to the homepage.

Comment: only hiding the download link is not the best option. Try to check the vip status and output the file. Maybe this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080341/correct-php-headers-for-pdf-file-download

Comment: I don't hide the download link ! 
I say if a VIP user share the download link , other users can download it without VIP account by enter link in browser !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You are not looking for .htaccess directive to do that. This is not .htaccess responsibility to distinguish between roles in your app. I think you should mark your users as vip in the database, and then check in session if the user is a vip. If the user has vip flag set - allow to download the file.

Comment: thanks for answering !
I've done these steps.
I checked if user vip , allow access to download file .
But on another occasion, user can share the link as free and another users can download that file without by VIP account .

Comment: You should check if user is vip before allowing to download file. I don't know how your app works, but maybe in fact you are looking for basic authentication: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: OK , how can i check ? 
I should check with .htaccess .
I should check if user is VIP or not . 
but how ?

Comment: Let's say you have a download link like following: `http://yoursite.com/download.php?file=fd456406745d816a45cae554c788e754`. Then in your download.php file you should  just check `if ($_SESSION['user']['vip'] === true) { // download} else { //redirect to login page}`. The files should be then placed under some other directory than document root, and set permissions in .htaccess file in that directory to `Order deny,allow
Deny from all`

Comment: I think this post can help understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127153/php-how-can-i-block-direct-url-access-to-a-file-but-still-allow-it-to-be-downl?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your Guidance.
I will try it tomorrow.