# PHP: How can I block direct URL access to an audio file, but still allow it to be viewed by logged in users but not to download?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have a Woocommerce website selling audio files. It must be viewed only for logged-in users who purchased, and should not be allowed to be downloaded. We have implemented this solution ([PHP: How can I block direct URL access to a file, but still allow it to be downloaded by logged in users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127153/php-how-can-i-block-direct-url-access-to-a-file-but-still-allow-it-to-be-downl)) of 'Victor' and it works fine to hide the exact file path, but it is downloading the file when we visit the link such as e.g. http://thesite.com/members/get_song.php?name=my-song-name. How can we make it to disable downloads of the file when visiting the link?

Comment: Chuck the files outside the docroot and have a PHP/JS filemanager (and/or audio player).

Comment: Making audio files play, but not downloadable, seems the difficult bit to me. You can never protect it completely, but you can make it very difficult. Have a look at this intro: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro PS: I wouldn't call this 'puchased' music however, it is more like a subscription.

Comment: To underline how difficult it can be, to protect your content, take [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/go#feature-chart). That's also a subscription service. Yet it is still easy to find ways to download its content: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-download-from-soundcloud-4570907

Comment: And by the way, if someone want the sound or file, he can use a program to record the played sound on your website. So in this case I would add a beep in every audio file every 10 seconds or so. In the bought version the beep is removed. Just to think about...