# How can I block direct URL access to all file in a folder, but still allow it to be downloaded by users?

Tags: php, html

i have a folder with name   uploads and have files i want to block direct download i readed an used  this link [PHP: How can I block direct URL access to a file, but still allow it to be downloaded by logged in users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127153/php-how-can-i-block-direct-url-access-to-a-file-but-still-allow-it-to-be-downl) in stackoverflow but it just not work and just  download a Broken file

this is my code
 .htaccess file

```
 Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
```

php file

```
  <?php



if( !empty( $_REQUEST['name'] )&& !empty( $_REQUEST['user'] ) && !empty( $_REQUEST['pass'] ) )
{
 include 'include/DbHandler.php';
$db = new DbHandler();
   $user= $_REQUEST['user'];
  $pass= $_REQUEST['pass'];
  $file_name= $_REQUEST['name'];
 // file name like this : hps.jpg
      $nest = $db->checkuserpass($user,$pass,$file_name);
 if ($nest!=2) 
  {
  /// user have premision for download 

    function getExtension($file){
        preg_match('/\.[^\.]+$/i', $file, $ext);
        return $ext[0];
    }

    //File type 
    $file_type = getExtension($file_name);



    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    //header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
    header('Content-Type: '.$file_type);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize("$file_name"));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile("$file_name");
    exit;


  }
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of denying access by .htaccess file you could save your file at a folder outside public side of your server, that is, outside www directory.

Comment: All file in uploads folder uploaded by website user if i change upload folder to outside www user olso can upload file directly ?

Comment: yes you can upload file directly. Just access this outside directory using .. for instance move_uploaded_file($arquivo_tmp,"../../temp/$namefile")

Comment: if this answer is helpful to you don't forget to click in green flag of this answer

Comment: Thanks but other user can't able direct download from outside www directory