# Cakephp app/webroot/img folder is directly accessible

Tags: cakephp-2.4

[image: Apache folder listing screenshot]

In url `localhost/newproject/app/webroot/admin/` all images are directly viewable in form of listings. Images should be accessible in webpage but not directly through folder.

Comment: here is post related to your question, maybe it will help you. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679524/block-direct-access-to-a-file-over-http-but-allow-php-script-access
just vote up this so we can know if this helps you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file in your directory where you need to prevent directly list of images and put this code :

```
Options -Indexes
```