# Apache access uploaded files only if logged in Yii2

Tags: apache, file-upload, yii2

Now if I log out from my basic Yii2 app (hosted on webserver), and I know direct url of an uploaded file, I can access and view it logged out also. My upload directory is under `app/web`. My webroot is `app/web`. Is there a way to restrict that only to logged in users? I guess it has to do more with apache, or? Thanks!

Comment: [here's what I was looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679524/block-direct-access-to-a-file-over-http-but-allow-php-script-access), excuse me I haven't found it sooner.

Comment: static files (pictures) inaccessible for app, too now...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yii does not restrict access to files. You'll have to save the files below the `web/`. I have not tried this my self, but I found this function that might help you

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#sendFile()-detail

```
public $this sendFile ( $filePath, $attachmentName = null, $options = [] )
```

**Edit based on your comment:**
If your download folder is below web, as in `frontend/downloads` it should not be accessible via a browser. But you can then send that file to the user using

```
public function actionTest()
{
    Yii::$app->response->sendFile(Yii::getAlias('@frontend').'/download/yourfile.zip');
}
```

Comment: upload folder is already under `/web/`. I don't understand how do you mean this function can help.

Comment: Then either i misunderstood your question, or you did not read up on that function. Provided an example in my answer as an edit. Is this not what you're asking?

Comment: The problem is, that the files are at the moment (basic app) **always** accessible. And I don't want that.

Comment: Well, not if you have them in `frontend/downloads` and you've set your htdocs/document root to the web folder.

Comment: I guess its `app/fronted` or something in Basic, but you'll be able to access them trough a localhost if your apache is configured with a document root in the folder where the application is placed. When you upload it to a webserver, and set your document root to the `web`folder, anything below that folder will not be accessible trough the browser. Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean everything **above** web folder is inaccessible, or?

Comment: If you point your document root to the web folder, everything in the web folder are accessible to a browser. So yes, i guess  that technically is above - my bad :)