# Organize php project files

Tags: php, project-organization

I'm new to the web development, recently I create a web application with Php/Mysql, and now I want to put it on to the server but I feel that my files organization is bad (very bad).

my project files structure looks something like that

```
|--XAMPP htdocs
    |--MyProject
        |--config.php
        |--functions.php
        |--header.php
        |--nav.php
        |--index.php
        |--js   
        |--css
        |--images
        |--register
            |--index.php
        |--messages
            |--inbox
                |--index.php
                |--handle_inbox.php
            |--outbox
                |--index.php
                |--handle_outbox.php
            |--trash
                |--index.php
                |--handle_trash.php
            |--uploaded_files
        |-- ...
```

what I can do to improve this structure and make it secure ?!

Comment: A very nice question but  the answer is opinion based. BTW you can't have the same directory several times (messages) at the same root.

Comment: Hard to comment on security without knowing your project.

Comment: @Progrock at least how I can make config.php file and uploaded_files  directory inaccessible !

Comment: If you are using Apache, for instance, there are some configurations to avoid a file (like config.php) being server and to block the contents of a directory.

Comment: @BBeta, please find my answer below. Also the generic recommendation would be, as soon as you are new to PHP development, to use even a simple PHP Framework, it will allow you to structure the code, files, and organize them in a good architectural way. You may start with the **CodeIgniter**, it's extremely lightweight.

Comment: @Farside I write most of code for the project, It's impossible to rewrite it in framework, even if it's possible I want to learn more about PHP before using any framework, for your answer I'm trying now to understand how listed framework do the job ...

Comment: @EddeAlmeida do you have some links plz ?

Comment: @Farside is completely right in his answer. Even if you don't want (or can't) rewrite your whole project using a framework, at least you should observe a framework closely and use its security practices. I'm going to post some links anyway.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/174708/apache2-how-do-i-restrict-access-to-a-directory-but-allow-access-to-one-file-w

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679524/block-direct-access-to-a-file-over-http-but-allow-php-script-access

Comment: @EddeAlmeida thnx for those useful links

Answer (score 16):

Paul M. Jones has done some fantastic research into common practice of tens of thousands of github projects in the realm of PHP. He has compiled a standard filesystem structure based on this research. Take a look at the [Standard PHP Package Skeleton](https://github.com/php-pds/skeleton) and base your project off of it.

You do not need all of the file structure that he recommends, but it's a great place to start. If you are planning to open-source your project, this file structure will make the most sense to your potential contributors and users.

Comment: I don't quite understand this. If I'm creating a login system with a login.php login form that contains PHP and HTML, this has to go in `/src` or `/public`?

Comment: @user2924019 The current way to build a PHP / HTML site is to separate your concerns. Do not combine your HTML and PHP in the same file unless you are using it as a templating system (place in `/src`) to generate your publicly viewable HTML (place in `/public`) or to dynamically build HTML via front-end controller. Further reading: https://phptherightway.com/#templating

Comment: I've been forcing myself to learn Laravel. It makes a lot of sense to keep these separate, and I do quite like the framework despite how much of a pain it was to get it setup and working on a Plesk server! I will check out the link now.

Answer (score 7):

The recommendation would be to have all the script "hidden" from straight access, and to have separately **public** directory.

You may check the best practices from different frameworks, how they organize the directories:

- [Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.project.html),
- [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure),
- [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html#structuring-the-application).

I'd recommend to guide these best practices, as they came to this through the long way and tons of tries.